# Mixitup save active to cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, save

I'm looking for a solution to save the active filtering sittings. So if anybody change the site (intern) and go back to the mixitup Portfolio site. I want that the Filtering settings are the same as he visit first the site.
For example if I filter cars. And come back not "all" is checked in the filter. "Cars" musst be selected.

I want to save filtering settings in cookies so if the user comes back the filter show his last settings. And i use the script from mixitup.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is you question.

Comment: I want to save filtering settings in cookies so if the user comes back the filter show his last settings. Ansld i usw the script from mixitup.